# Emberjs Object avoid switch case method hash

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember object that has several actions :

```
MyObject = Ember.Object.extend {
 action1: ->
  console.log "do 1"

 action2: ->
  console.log "do 2"
}
```

I'd like to call one of these action depending on some condition. The easy way is
to check for this condition and call the needed condition using `if` or `switch-case`. But, I need something more scalable like a hash of method inside my object and invoke the needed method by just sending their name like `object.exec('action1')`.

Does ember object has already this feature ?

Comment: Did you try something like: `obj.get('action1').apply(obj, yourarguments)` ?

Comment: I got an error :  Funtion.prototype.apply: Arguments list was wrong type

Comment: `apply` takes two arguments: the value for `this`, and an array of arguments. If you wants to pass arguments without put them in an array, you should use `call` which takes the value for `this` as the first argument, and all others arguments are directly passed to the method. I suggest you to read the first answer: http://goo.gl/5z6yx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick implementation of a dynamic methods' call method in javascript.

```
var obj = {
 action1 : function(item) {
    return item;
 }, 
 action2 : function(item) { 
    return item;
 }, 

 exec:function(name){
    if(this[name] ==== 'undefined') return;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return this[name](args.slice(1,args.length))
 }
}

obj.exec('action1','Hello')
obj.exec('action2','World')

Should return Hello World
```